# How to change the head attributes of Iframe Dynamically in Asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to update the iframe header attributes dynamically before loading into the content window in Mvc Application

Ex:
url="https:localhost:8020/dashboard/stockanalysis?mode=ios7"

updating the src of iframe using query string  like this

https:localhost:8020/dashboard/stockanalysis?mode=windows"

thise scenarios works well in normal .html application

how to achieve this in MVC asp.net application ?

Comment: Can your elaborate your question a bit more with actual requirement - what has been done so far and what supposed to be completed?

Comment: i want to add and remove the head attributes dynamically to the iframe element before i pass my query string                                                Ex:   At initial if the frame element with src=https:localhost:8020/dashboard/stockanalysis?mode=ios7   means  after clicking the  button i want  to  update the mode using query string like this  to the frame element https:localhost:8020/dashboard/stockanalysis?mode=windows"

Comment: You can use JQuery to set the `src` of iFrame, for example - `$('#iframeId').attr('src','your url here');`

Comment: It works well for normal html application but  coming for MVC the head attributes is not updated properly

Comment: What do you mean by not updating properly, can you show us some code?